# How can I check audit log to find deleted site information

Tags: 2007

I am in a moss 2007 site, and found a deleted sub site, how can I know who deleted the site and when?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have auditing turned on:

View audit log reports

1. On the site collection home page, click Site Actions, point to Site Settings, and then click Modify All Site Settings.
2. In the Site Collection Administration section, select Audit log reports.
3. Select the type of report that you need: (In this case) Deletion    Reports what content has been deleted

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA010100005.aspx